# Как динамически при выборе select менять курс в калькуляторе?

Tags: javascript

Код:

```js
document.getElementById("selsel").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var opt = this.value;
    var get = document.getElementById('psevdo');
if (opt == 4 ) {
  document.getElementById('whats').innerHTML = "Введите сумму в [USD]: ";
  get.value='500'; 
  calculate2(7000);
} else {
  document.getElementById('whats').innerHTML = "Введите сумму в [RUB]: ";
  get.value='100';
  calculate2(100);
}
});
function calculate2(st_q) {
  var min = 0.01;
  var ser_pr = 100;
  var sum_insert = parseFloat(st_q);
  $('#res_sum').html( (sum_insert * ser_pr).toFixed(0) );
    $('#wm_summ').val(sum_insert);
}
```

```html
<form name="pay_is" action="" method="post">
    <table  border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>

          <input type="hidden" name="m" value="<?=$fk_merchant_id?>">
          <div id="whats">Введите сумму в [РУБ]:</div>
          <div id="whats1">
            <input type="text" type="number" value="100"  name="sum" size="7" id="psevdo" onchange="calculate2(this.value)" onkeyup="calculate2(this.value)" onfocusout="calculate2(this.value)" onactivate="calculate2(this.value)" ondeactivate="calculate2(this.value)">
            
            Вы получите <span id="res_sum">10000</span> материала
          </div>


      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
валюта:&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <select size="1" name="service" id="selsel">
         <option selected="selected" value="1">рубли</option>
         <option value="4"> доллары</option>
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">
       <input type="submit" name="pay_is" class="sumserf2" value="обменять">
     </td>
   </tr>  
 </table>   
</form>
```

У меня тут две проблемы:

1. не работает онлайн калькулятор
2. не знаю как динамически при выборе `select` менять курс в калькуляторе

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crystaltrumpet/2ynopzj1/13/)

Comment: А что конкретно не работает? Какой результат ожидается? Приведённый Вами код вполне себе работает.

Comment: не работает: при смене валюты на доллар - я не знаю как сделать так чтобы  где динамечески должно изменяться курс на доллар.  - "Вы получите 10000 материала" 
1 рубль - 100 материала
1 доллар - 7000 материала

Comment: так оно и сейчас так работает. jQuery только подключите.

Comment: нет. к сожалению не работает. когда Вы выбираете доллары и вводите сумму к примеру 10 - должно писаться: "Вы получите 70000 материала"

Comment: Когда вы в окне input начинаете вводить сумму -
В строке:
"Вы получите 10000 материала" - должен динамически меняться калькулятор - функция calculate2 должен считать исходя из курса ser_pr = 100 а когда доллар ser_pr = 7000;

Comment: Каким образом можно реализовать:
если выбрана валюта рубль - значит переменная var ser_pr = 100;
если выбрана валюта доллар- значит переменная var ser_pr = 7000;?
Буду благодарен за подсказку

Comment: я ниже ответил на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код был вполне себе рабочим, но Вам стоило подключить jQuery, если хотите использовать эту библиотеку. (Хотя, на мой взгляд, здесь она очень даже лишняя. Тянуть библиотеку только ради изменения содержимого пары элементов явно не стоит) 
Получить выбранную валюту можно так: `document.getElementById('selsel').value`.
Помимо этого не стоит навешивать кучу однотипных событий на элемент - одного вполне себе предостаточно. И вместо инлайн событий (`onkeyup`, `onkeydown`, etc.) лучше использовать `elem.addEventListener`для разделения вёрстки и логики - в будущем проблем будет меньше. 
Ниже предоставил исправленный пример.

```js
document.getElementById('psevdo').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => calculate2(e.target.value));
document.getElementById("selsel").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var opt = this.value;
  var get = document.getElementById('psevdo');
  if (opt == 4) {
    document.getElementById('whats').innerHTML = "Введите сумму в [USD]: ";
    get.value = '500';
    calculate2(500);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('whats').innerHTML = "Введите сумму в [RUB]: ";
    get.value = '100';
    calculate2(100);
  }
});

function calculate2(st_q) {
  var min = 0.01;
  var ser_pr = +document.getElementById('selsel').value === 1 ? 100 : 7000;
  var sum_insert = parseFloat(st_q) * ser_pr;
  document.getElementById('res_sum').textContent = sum_insert;
  document.getElementById('res_sum').value = parseFloat(st_q);
}
```

```html
<form name="pay_is" action="" method="post">
  <table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="m" value="<?=$fk_merchant_id?>">
        <div id="whats">Введите сумму в [РУБ]:</div>
        <div id="whats1">
          <input type="text" type="number" value="100" name="sum" size="7" id="psevdo"> Вы получите <span id="res_sum">10000</span> материала
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        валюта:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select size="1" name="service" id="selsel">
          <option selected="selected" value="1">рубли</option>
          <option value="4"> доллары</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="pay_is" class="sumserf2" value="обменять">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Гениально! все заработало! Огромное Вам спасибо. Буду изучать javascript!